# forEach JSTL loop for dropdown list no value is passing

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans, el

I have forEach JSTL loop that is going through ArrayList of several states in javabean name State.

```
 <%         State state = new State();
            pageContext.setAttribute("state", state);%>

            <select name="state">
            <c:forEach items="${state.states}" var="state">
                <option value="${state}>
                ${state}
                </option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select><br>
```

For some reason value of each option is null. But EL between option tags evaluates correctly.

Below my java Bean class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class State implements Serializable{

private ArrayList states = new ArrayList();


public State() {
    states.add("Massachusetts");
    states.add("New Hampshire");
    states.add("Connecticut");
    states.add("Rhode Island");
}

public ArrayList getStates() {
    return states;
}

public void setStates(ArrayList states) {
    this.states = states;
}

}
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your controller code

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${state.states}" var="state">`
You're mixing up the names of your variables. You're browsing the content of state.states and store the current one in state, so you basically override it and have strange effects. Just use `var="item"` and use that in you option rather than state.

Comment: There is no servlet. Only jsp and javabean which set attribute javabean object.

Comment: @EricDarchis I don't see any difference between your code and mine

Comment: Think of your case in plain Java. You assign the currently iterated item to exactly the same variable as where the for loop is iterating over. How would that ever work? Give it a different variable name like `var="currentState"` and retry.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I found out my code is working correctly. It didn't pass value because I didn't assign name in select tag to "state".

Answer (score 0):

is not there are mess with names, when you are using

```
 State state = new State();     
  pageContext.setAttribute("state", state);
```

and

```
<option value="${state}">${state}</option>
```

in your c:forEach ?